# What is she saying?

Tags: listening

I cannot get what she is saying in the middle part of her talk.

Here is the link to the audio file:

> http://s8.picofile.com/d/8351258634/321d06a3-70a1-45d6-833c-79c5a9efcdcc/clip.m4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what she says:

> Maybe, I'd still get the award and the money that way.

Can you hear it better now? "I'd", by the way, is a contraction of *I would*.